# What is the best way to loop bluebird promises

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

Now I've working on NodeJS and Sequelize to query and process an database data.
I've call findAll from Table1 and I want to query each rows to apply some data to Table2 then I want to add all data to array before send output, I did like this

```
var last_promise;
var output_results = {};
Table1Model.findAll()
.then(function(results1)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < results1.length; ++i)
    {
        var result1 = results1[i];
        output_results[result1.id] = result1;
        var add_promise = Table2Model
            .create({
                id_from_table1: result1.id,
                data_from_table1: result1.data
            });
            .then(function(result2) {
                output_results[result2.id_from_table1].data2 = result2;
            });
            if (last_promise)
            {
                last_promise.then(function()
                {
                    return add_promise;
                });
            } else {
                last_promise = add_promise;
            }
        }
    }
}
last_promise.then(function() {
    return output_results;
}
```

I want to know that there any better way to execute promises sequentially in a loop like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can do that with `.all()` method:

```
Table1Model
  .findAll()
  .then(function(results1) {
    return Promise.all(results1.map(function(result) {
      return Table2Model
        .create({
            id_from_table1: result1.id,
            data_from_table1: result1.data
        })
        .then(function(result2) {
            ...
        });
    }));
  })
  .then(function(output_results) {
  });
```

Comment: Sorry if my answer is not complete, but it's a bit hard to follow your code flow and I think it's easier if you play a bit around `Promise.all()`. I hope that helps!

Comment: Great !!, this really help me just keep all promises variables in array then call Promise.all(theArray);

Thank for your answer :)